# MPI prime numbers

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, primes

I wanted to find paralel algorithm which finds prime numbers with mpi library.I found this one but when i run on code block,always i get

```
    Sorry - this exercise requires an even number of tasks.
   evenly divisible into 2500000 .  Try 4 or 8.



 What it means?how can i obtain number of tasks.
```

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/samples/C/mpi_prime.c

Answer (score 1):

> What it means?

It means that you probably have to take a look at the source code and try to understand how it works. High Performance Mark has already pointed to the right MPI call and if you look at the beginning of the `main` function, you'd see these lines:

```c
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&ntasks);
if (((ntasks%2) !=0) || ((LIMIT%ntasks) !=0)) {
   printf("Sorry - this exercise requires an even number of tasks.\n");
   printf("evenly divisible into %d.  Try 4 or 8.\n",LIMIT);
   MPI_Finalize();
   exit(0);
   }
```

Obviously it requires an even number of MPI processes (otherwise `ntasks%2 != 0`) and this number should also divide `LIMIT` (which is equal to `2500000` in this case). MPI programs should be executed through the MPI launcher, which in most cases is called `mpiexec` or `mpirun`. It takes the number of processes as a parameter. If you do not run the code through `mpiexec`, most MPI implementations behave as if the program was started using

```
mpiexec -np 1 ./program
```

`1` is not even, hence the first part of the `if` condition evaluates to true and the abort code gets executed.

What you should do is either run the program in a terminal using `mpiexec -np <# of procs> executable`, where `<# of procs>` is the desired number of MPI processes and `executable` is the name of the executable file. `<# of procs>` should be even and should divide `2500000`. I would suggest to go with `2`, `4` or `8`. `10` would also do. You won't see any improvement in the speed unless your development system has multicore CPU or/and several CPUs.

You mention Code::Blocks. See [here](http://www.blog.kubiak.co.uk/post/44) on some ideas of how to make it run MPI programs through `mpiexec`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to get the number of processes during the execution of an MPI program is to call the `MPI_COMM_SIZE` subroutine, like this

```
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr)
```

where `num_procs` is an integer which will equal the number of processes after the call has completed.  I expect that what you call a *task* is the same as what I call a *process*.

Note that I've written the call in Fortran, C and C++ bindings are also available though the latter seem to be going out of favour.

Comment: ok i found whats problem there are   optional parts in code 

/***** Optional: print each prime as it is found

like that but still ı dont know how can i  obtain processor number.For example i want to see how fast when i use 3 or 5 or 10 processor